# Photo overlay python - image appears blurry

Tags: python

Image appears blurry! I have built (copied) this code which helps me overlay a circle image, however the sides of the circle are blurry, is there an easier way to overlay images? Any help would be appreciated

`````
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import pyautogui as pg




fo = int(input("Choose circle size (MAX 500): "))

root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "#000002")
root.geometry("1000x1000")

label = Label(root, height=900, width=900, bg="#000002", border=0)
label.pack()


def place_center():  # Placing the window in the center of the screen
    global x, y
    reso = pg.size()
    rx = reso[0]
    ry = reso[1]
    x = int((rx / 2) - (500 / 2))
    y = int((ry / 2) - (500 / 2))
    root.geometry(f"500x500+{x}+{y}")


place_center()

img = Image.open("kk.png")
img = img.resize((fo, fo))

imagem = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
label.configure(image=imagem)

root.mainloop()````
`````

Comment: Could it be that the image you are using is much smaller than the dimensions you're setting it to?